# Logged events not showing up in Ganache or in Transaction log

Tags: blockchain, solidity, hardhat, ganache

So I am triggering this contract's fallback(from another contract) which emits an event, This event shows up in remix but not in ganache or while test.

Target Contract

```
contract ContractA {
    event logMsgData (bytes, uint);

    fallback() external payable {
        console.log("here");
        emit logMsgData(msg.data, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Caller

```
contract ContractB {
    BookTicket public targetContract;

    constructor(address _targetContract) {
        targetContract = ContractA(payable(_targetContract));
    }

    function callFallbackUsingSignature() public {
        (bool success,) = address(targetContract).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("nonExistingFunction()"));
        require(success);
    }
}
```

now when I run `callFallbackUsingSignature()` it does trigger the fallback (as indicated by remix and console.log) but it does not show up on ganache

[image]

or in transaction log

```
{
  to: '0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  contractAddress: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  gasUsed: BigNumber { value: "31630" },
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000',
  blockHash: '0x28544824c41f6791ca1b0c9abec71d867e14e571598f795fb23385c4ceaabda8',
  transactionHash: '0x6f1ae658afe454af1173c3cce8a3ce152c91a5fcb6ea3af6e31b3b72f04d6527',
  logs: [
    {
      transactionIndex: 0,
      blockNumber: 6,
      transactionHash: '0x6f1ae658afe454af1173c3cce8a3ce152c91a5fcb6ea3af6e31b3b72f04d6527',
      address: '0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0',
      topics: [Array],
      data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004f85396d700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      logIndex: 0,
      blockHash: '0x28544824c41f6791ca1b0c9abec71d867e14e571598f795fb23385c4ceaabda8'
    }
  ],
  blockNumber: 6,
  confirmations: 1,
  cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { value: "31630" },
  effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { value: "1458563173" },
  status: 1,
  type: 2,
  byzantium: true,
  events: [
    {
      transactionIndex: 0,
      blockNumber: 6,
      transactionHash: '0x6f1ae658afe454af1173c3cce8a3ce152c91a5fcb6ea3af6e31b3b72f04d6527',
      address: '0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0',
      topics: [Array],
      data: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004f85396d700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      logIndex: 0,
      blockHash: '0x28544824c41f6791ca1b0c9abec71d867e14e571598f795fb23385c4ceaabda8',
      removeListener: [Function (anonymous)],
      getBlock: [Function (anonymous)],
      getTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      getTransactionReceipt: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  ]
}
```

And when i test it, no matter which args i give the test always passes

```
expect(await contractB.callFallbackUsingSignature()).to.emit(contractA, "logMsgData").withArgs("0xf853", 0);
```

So how do I test event emission? What am I doing wrong.